# Getting "0xc000007b Application Unable to Start Correctly" error on only one computer

Tags: c++, windows, exe

I am building an application, and I just pulled the source code onto a new computer.  I am able to compile and build the program on the new computer, but when I try to run the executable I get an "Application start correctly" error.

I can take the executable that was built on the problem computer run it on my other machines and it works fine.  Dependency Walker doesn't highlight any obvious deficiencies; the output looks similar to the output from the functioning machines.  I also reinstalled the VS C++ redistributable.

It seems like there must be some way in which the environment on the new computer is different, but I don't know where or how to start looking.

Comment: Maybe an ActiveX or COM library is missing?

Comment: It's definitely possible.  What would be a good way to check that?

Comment: `0x0000007b` or `0xC000007b` which is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT` ?

Comment: 0xc000007b, you're right.  I missed the 'c' when I was typing the title.

Comment: Maybe the OS is 32 bits and the executable 64 bits?

Comment: That error definitely comes up when you've built a 64 bit program, but that program tries to load 32-bit libraries, or you've built a 32-bit program and the app is trying to load 64-bit libraries.  You need to check the bit-ness of the app you've built, the libraries it tries to load, and the bit-ness of the OS you're running on.

Comment: In addition, the way Windows attempts to load DLL's is that the first DLL that matches the name that Window's searches for is the DLL that will attempt to be loaded.  So you're out of luck if the Window's DLL search logic finds a 64-bit DLL hat happens to have the same name as a 32-bit DLL, and your app is 32-bit (and the same thing vice-versa).  So probably the machine with the issue could have 64 bit (or 32-bit) DLL's with same names, and Windows search logic finds the incorrect ones first.

Comment: That's great, thanks @PaulMcKenzie.  Is DependencyWalker the best way to try to track this down?

Comment: Dependency Walker can help.  In Dependency Walker, there is a "CPU" column in one of the panes.  For the row that describes your app, check this column and see if it's x86 or x64,  If it's x86, then this is a 32-bit app, else it's a 64-bit app.  Then check the bitness of the dependent libraries.  If they all check out fine, then possibly there is a library being loaded via `LoadLibrary`, and this is causing the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I ran Dependency Walker and it identified two x86 libraries that it was using.  Interestingly, when I run DW on the computers that are functioning, the same libraries show up as x86, but no error is thrown.  Anyway, I was able to depricate the portion of the code that used those libraries, and now everything works.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @PaulMcKenzie in the comments above.  My problem ended up being that I'm using an x64 application, and my Windows search path was finding and trying to use x86 DLLs, which caused the crash.  I found this out through a closer examination of the Dependency Walker output.